# How to get all comments in a given group?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-group

I am trying to get all messages posted in a given group on Facebook. However, I am failing to use FQL with Facebook C# SDK, so I tried something simple, like this:

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("/groups/GroupID/feed/");
```

But then I got the following exception:

```
(OAuthException) Unknown path components: /feed
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FQL, is possible to do as follows:

```
                var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);

                var query = string.Format("select actor_id, attachment, message from stream where source_id = {0}", "groupId");

                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.q = query;

                dynamic result = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use fb.get("/" + groupID + "?fields=feed.limit(10).fields(type,message)");
this should get you an array or message in the groups, but i am having trouble getting the message into string in c#